# repeat items in a php array until they match the count of another array

Tags: php, arrays

I've created two arrays from strings using `explode()` one called `$labels` and the other called `$colors`. What I'd like to do is check the count of the items in `$labels` and if there are less items in `$colors` I'd like the values of the `$colors` array to be repeated until the count matches. If there are more items in `$colors` than in `$labels` I'd like to reduce remove items from the `$colors` array until it matches the number of items in `$labels`.

I assume I can use `count()` or `array_legnth()` in a conditional to compare the number of items between the two arrays and that I'm going to have to use some kind of while loop but really not sure how to get started.

Is there a better way or function I should use to compare the two arrays? And how would I go about repeating or deleting the items in the second array so that I land up with the same number of items in each?

Comment: Show your as it looks now

Comment: see the answer selected as correct for how mine looks - as the comment below says - its exactly what I've used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do :

```
// the two arrays
$labels = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$colors = array(1, 2, 3, 4);


// only if the two arrays don't hold the same number of elements
if (count($labels) != count($colors)) {
    // handle if $colors is less than $labels
    while (count($colors) < count($labels)) {
        // NOTE : we are using array_values($colors) to make sure we use 
        //        numeric keys. 
        //        See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)
        $colors = array_merge($colors, array_values($colors));
    }

    // handle if $colors has more than $labels
    $colors = array_slice($colors, 0, count($labels));
}

// your resulting arrays    
var_dump($labels, $colors);
```

Put that into an utility function and you will be good to go.

Comment: While all three of these answers have definitely helped my thinking, this hit the nail on the head and knocked out exactly the solution I was after first time.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont found the anwer use this function:

```
$labels = array("a","b","c","d","e");
$colors = array("green","blue","red");

function fillArray($biggerArray,$smallerArray) {
    $forTimes         = (sizeof($biggerArray)-sizeof($smallerArray));
    $finalArray       = $smallerArray;
    for($i=0;$i < $forTimes ;$i++) {
        shuffle($smallerArray);
        array_push($finalArray,$smallerArray[0]);
    }
    return $finalArray;
}
```

Usage:

```
   $newColorsArray = fillArray($labels,$colors);
   print_r($newColorsArray);
```

It returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => green
    [1] => blue
    [2] => red
    [3] => blue
    [4] => red
)
```

Comment: while this is helpful in my thinking around this problem its not quite the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) function to go through one or the other array and populate values.

```
if ( count($labels) > count($colors) ) {
   array_walk($labels, 'fill_other_array');
} else if (count($colors) > count($labels) {
   array_walk($colors, 'fill_other_array');
}

function fill_other_array() {
   ...
   array_fill(...);
}
```

This is not very efficient at the moment because it will go over the entire array, rather than just the difference, but I'll leave some of the code up to you. :)

Or you could do something like your own idea where you either loop through the shorter array or just fill it with a single value like the last one in the array.

```
if ( count($labels) > count($colors) ) {
   $colors = array_fill(count($colors), count($labels) - count($colors), $colors[count($colors)-1]);  // fill with last value in the array
} else if (count($colors) > count($labels) {
   ...
}
```

To reduce the number of elements in the array, you can use [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

Comment: will need to play with these array functions a little more as I clearly don't understand them entirely.  I'm not sure at this point in my understanding how I would compare the arrays more efficiently but I get what you're saying and  will keep it in mind and have to do some digging:)